# How to create a rest client with service endpoint url and no java classes given?

Tags: json, web-services, rest, rest-client, advanced-rest-client

I have been given a rest service endpoint url, `http://edc.edu.com:8087/edc/connections/activate` and told to generate a client, it's using POST method and no data shall be passed, just a ping to the web service. How to create a client using just a url, the Application type used is JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome browser, then add the extension [Advanced Rest Client (ARC)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) . Using this client you can call your service using any HTTP method (GET,POST etc).You can set the application type to json  by setting the  content type to  'Content-Type: application/json'